# memory leak for simple program, how can I free allocs?

Tags: c

I am learning C, and am have a problem finding out how i can free my malloc()'s.

The program runs correctly..  but im Using valgrind and it is coming up with 8 allocs and 5 frees.  I need to be able to free 3 more.  I commented where I believe which I am not freeing but I am not sure of a solution.

Is there a way I can free up those allocs, or do I need to consider re-writing the tokenizer()?

Here is the code to the whole file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char *substr(const char *s, int from, int nchars) {

   char *result = (char *) malloc((nchars * sizeof(char))+1);
   strncpy(result, s+from, nchars);

   return result;
}

/**
 Extracts white-space separated tokens from s.
 @param s A string containing 0 or more tokens.
 @param ntokens The number of tokens found in s.
 @return A pointer to a list of tokens. The list and tokens must be freed
 by the caller.
 */ 
char **tokenize(const char *s, int *ntokens) {
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int toIndex = 0;
    char **list;
    int finalCount = *ntokens;
    int count = 0;

    list = malloc(*ntokens * sizeof(char*));

    while ( count < finalCount) {

        char *m = strchr(s,' ');
        toIndex = m - s;

        if(toIndex >= 0) {
            list[count] = substr(s,fromIndex,toIndex); // This substr() gets free'ed from main()        
            s = substr(s, toIndex+1, strlen(s));    // I believe This is where I am making extra mallocs that are not being freed
            count++;
        } else {        
            list[count] = substr(s,fromIndex,strlen(s)); // This substr() gets free'ed from main()
            count++;
        }
    }   

    return list;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char **list;
  char *string = "terrific radiant humble pig";

  int count = 4; // Hard-Coded

  list = tokenize(string, &count);

  for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    printf("list[%d] = %s\n", i, list[i]);
  }

  // Free mallocs()'s
  for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    free(list[i]);
  }
  // Free List
  free(list);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wierd, its not giving me any warrnings

Comment: Are you compiling with -Wall and -Werror?

Comment: Off topic, but `count++` does not have to be in the `if/else`, as you're incrementing count in both cases.

Comment: gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g -o sub sub.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need substr s everytime after getting one token. This is too wasteful, in terms of both time and spape. You can just change the value of s to make it point to the string you need.

```
//s = substr(s, toIndex+1, strlen(s));    // You don't need have to generate a new string
s = s + toIndex + 1;//You can just change the value of s to make it point to the string you need
```

Comment: +1 John you should accept @JackyZhu answer; he beat me by 58secs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround I can think of, by just storing the current value of s in another pointer before you overwrite. And also make sure not to free the first value of s got directly as the parameter to `tokenize()`.

```
char **tokenize(const char *s, int *ntokens) {
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int toIndex = 0;
    char **list;
    int finalCount = *ntokens;
    int count = 0;
    bool firstTime = true; // Use this to make sure you do not free up the memory for the initial s passed as the function arg

    list = malloc(*ntokens * sizeof(char*));

    while ( count < finalCount) {
        char *m = strchr(s,' ');
        toIndex = m - s;

        if(toIndex >= 0) {
            const char* previous_s = s; // Store the current value of s
            list[count] = substr(s,fromIndex,toIndex); // This substr() gets free'ed from main()        
            s = substr(previous_s, toIndex+1, strlen(previous_s));
            if (!firstTime)
            {
                free(previous_s); // Since we're done with the previous_s, we can free up the memory
            }
            firstTime = false;
            count++;
        } else {        
            list[count] = substr(s,fromIndex,strlen(s)); // This substr() gets free'ed from main()
            count++;
        }
    }   

    if (!firstTime)
    {
        free(s); // There could be a block allocated last time which needs to be freed as well
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I tested your tokenize but I'm sorry, the mail received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. in list[i] ..while executing for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
  printf("list[%d] = %s\n", i, list[i]);
 }

Comment: Missed the return list at the end of tokenize(), have updated the answer. But as JackyZhu pointed out, you need not allocate and free so much memory in the heap. His solution is much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly where you thought it was!
Luckily in c is very easy to move the point ,  at which a string, you do not need to call again `substr`;  because of pointers ;-)

```
// s = substr(s, toIndex+1, strlen(s));   
s += toIndex+1;
```